# Django ORM extra with multiple returns

Tags: python, django, django-1.3

Is there a way in Django 1.3.7 to return multiple values from one extra select?
For example I have two extra selects used to get two separate values, and i would also like to get their difference (I need to be able to filter on it) without needing an extra query:

```
invoices = invoices.extra(select={"value_storned_left": 
    add_invoice_storned_total_query()})
invoices = invoices.extra(select={"total_value_paid": 
    add_invoice_total_paid_query()})
```

I did not find a solution using annotate for this in Django 1.3 so I was wondering if can combine the two queries and also get the difference there and return 3 values from the same extra query, maybe get something like this:

```
invoices = invoices.extra(select={("value1", "value2", "value3"): 
    combined_query()})
```

Is there a way to do this and how would it look. 
The only method I found so far to do this was making and extra third query to get the difference, that uses what i do in the first 2 queries, so this takes longer and it;s heavier on the DB.

Thanks

Comment: There's really no good reason to be using Django 1.3. It has been unsupported for many years and is totally insecure. Upgrading to a more recent version would additionally give you access to the newer query features which would help address this problem.

Comment: i know, but I would like to be able to resolve this problem before I can actually upgrade to a newer version of django.

Comment: as has already been pointed out. It's futile.  You can do this using the new apis. So why do something just for the sake of throwing it away? It's not as if you will even learn anything usefull